# I cannot add Firebase Crashlytics CocoaPods to my Xcode project

Tags: firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I'm following instructions from https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-ios?hl=es-419

At this point:

```
$ pod repo add crashlytics git@github.com:crashlytics/SpecsEAP.git
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cloning spec repo `crashlytics` from `git@github.com:crashlytics/SpecsEAP.git` [!] /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:crashlytics/SpecsEAP.git -- crashlytics

Cloning into 'crashlytics'... ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I've checked the connection to GitHub:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi Username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I've also checked I have a valid SSH key:

```
$ ssh-add -l -E md5
4096 MD5:b0:26:2f:78:55:57:51:0f:71:17:6d:93:15:dd:67:a8 myemail@gmail.com (RSA)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the english version of the docs, those do not mention any of those repo-adding commands: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios. Looks like the spanish translation is outdated.

Comment: Thanks @Gereon. So easy when looking at the right doc! If you add this as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the english version of the docs, those do not mention any of those repo-adding commands: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios

Looks like the spanish translation is outdated.

Comment: I've upvoted this but It looks like I don't have enough reputation to make it public :( Anyway, thanks.